# Open simple PHP file with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP file on my server that stores one string `<div id="username">my.username</div>`. The URL is http://intranet/text.php.

I would like to use some jQuery/Javascript to read this file and grab this element value.

I had tried to put something together **but not sure how to open the file with JS**.

```
'use strict';

var template = '<div id="username">replace-me</div>';

var output = document.createElement('div');

output.innerHTML = template;
output.querySelector('#username').innerHTML = 'get replaced';

console.log(output.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Try using Ajax to retreive PHP page's output.

Comment: @RomanHocke Thank you for this. Do you have an example of something similar to this or should I just Google? :)

Comment: This looks good: http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/N7avm/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$('#username').load('http://intranet/text.php #username');
```

This should load the content of that remove `<div>` into your old `<div>`.

---

How it works:

- The bit `$('#username')` will select the element with id `username` inside your page.
- The load method, when you pass a string, will try to load HTML from a remote location, splitting the string by the space. (Internally, it will use a `$.get` on the URL)
- The `#username` bit, after the URL, will apply to the fetched HTML. (The space is important)

This code uses the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/)! I've answered in jQuery since it is one of the tags.

Comment: If I want to echo the value out on that page, how do I do this?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk That depends on what you mean with "echo the value out".

Comment: Apologies. I mean display the value of username on the same page. Just to make sure it actually works.

Comment: I tried `alert(#username);` but got an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` error.

Comment: That alert doesn't work. The character `#` is an invalid character there. And you can do it in many ways. The one I've written is made to fit your needs that you expressed on the question. I think I know what your problem is. I don't know how your file structure is, but you can do it with PHP only (using an `include`). But, my jQuery needs a fix. Should look like this: `$.get('http://intranet/text.php', function(data){ $(data).appendTo(document.body); });`. Can you try it?

Comment: Thank you for this. How do I grab the `username` value alone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123229/discussion-between-michaelmcgurk-and-ismael-miguel).

Answer (score 1):

Try ajax as follow:

```
$.ajax({

    url:"your-phpfile.php",

    success:function(data)
    {
           //data 'll hold the output of the php file
    }
})
```

Remember before doing this include jquery library.

Comment: Do you know if this will work on a local file on the Intranet?

Comment: It 'll work on a local file on intranet, I am sure. But you need to enable CORS in PHP side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to retrieve PHP file like this.

```
var template = null;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://intranet/text.php', true);
req.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if(req.status == 200){
      template = data.responseText;
      var output = document.createElement('div');

      output.innerHTML = template;
      output.querySelector('#username').innerHTML = 'get replaced';

      console.log(output.innerHTML);
    }
    else{
      dump("An error occured");
    }
  }
};
req.send(null);
```

This code is in pure JS, cause i saw that you were not working with JQuery

Comment: I will try right now - will post back shortly - thank you :)

Comment: I get the error `test.html:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else`

Comment: Of course, my bad, edit done, missed `{}` on my `if`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately on this line `output.querySelector('#username').innerHTML = 'get replaced';` I still get the error: `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` - is it not reading the file properly?

Comment: The problem is that you're querySelector is null